# GOOGLE DOCS API Invalid requests[0].updateTextStyle: Index 4 must be less than the end index of the referenced segment, 2.",

Tags: api, documentation

I've created a document using Google Docs API, but when I try to modify its options or add text, it gives me this error:

http://prntscr.com/naf0nm

The thing is if I open the document and click `enter` many times ( to make many lines) then execution and modification works. Can anyone help me?? What do I need to do to not get this error?

```
        String text1 = "hola, llegó papa";

        List<Request> requests = new ArrayList<>();
        requests.add(new Request().setInsertText(new InsertTextRequest()
                .setText(text1)
                .setLocation(new Location().setIndex(25))));
        BatchUpdateDocumentRequest body = new BatchUpdateDocumentRequest().setRequests(requests);
        BatchUpdateDocumentResponse response = service.documents()
                .batchUpdate(idDoc, body).execute();
```

Here the method to create doc:

```
private static void createDoc(Docs service) throws IOException {
        Document doc = new Document()
                .setTitle("TEXTO CAMBIADO");
        doc = service.documents().create(doc)
                .execute();
        System.out.println("Created document with title: " + doc.getTitle());   


        idDoc = doc.getDocumentId();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It is very late for answer but it can help to others.

May be this answer can help you. [someone has answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57300083/unable-to-add-text-to-new-google-doc-via-docs-api)

Also you have to write backword to get the last inserted text at the starting of doc.

**I just found another way to write text at end of doc. You don't need to set the location, just do this way..**

```
public void insertText(Docs docsService) throws IOException {
    List<Request> requests = new ArrayList<>();
    requests.add(new Request().setInsertText(new InsertTextRequest()
            .setText("Name : {{NAME}}\n")
            .setEndOfSegmentLocation(new EndOfSegmentLocation())));

    requests.add(new Request().setInsertText(new InsertTextRequest()
            .setText("\nDOB: {{DOB}}\n")
            .setEndOfSegmentLocation(new EndOfSegmentLocation())));

    requests.add(new Request().setInsertText(new InsertTextRequest()
            .setText("\nMobile: {{MOBILE}}\n")
            .setEndOfSegmentLocation(new EndOfSegmentLocation())));

    BatchUpdateDocumentRequest body = new BatchUpdateDocumentRequest().setRequests(requests);
    BatchUpdateDocumentResponse response = docsService.documents()
            .batchUpdate(Constants.DOCUMENT_ID, body).execute();
}
```

Comment: This answer does not explain the issue or fix for the actual error posted on the question. Link points to a different issue.