# Unable to add text to new Google Doc via Docs API

Tags: java, google-docs-api

My program is creating documents and each document has text that needs to go into it. Any attempt to call an `InsertTextRequest` invokes an error.

```java
List<Request> requests = new ArrayList<>();

requests.add(new Request().setInsertText(new InsertTextRequest()
                .setText("Simple test.")
                .setLocation(new Location().setIndex(0))));

BatchUpdateDocumentRequest body = new BatchUpdateDocumentRequest()
                .setRequests(requests);

BatchUpdateDocumentResponse response = docService.documents()
                .batchUpdate(file.getId(), body).execute();
```

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Invalid requests[0].insertText: The insertion index must be inside the bounds of an existing paragraph. You can still create new paragraphs by inserting newlines.",
    "reason" : "badRequest"
  } ],
  "message" : "Invalid requests[0].insertText: The insertion index must be inside the bounds of an existing paragraph. You can still create new paragraphs by inserting newlines.",
  "status" : "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
```

Even trying to add a newline character before adding the text does not fix this issue.

```java
List<Request> requests = new ArrayList<>();

requests.add(new Request().setInsertText(new InsertTextRequest()
                .setText("\n")
                .setLocation(new Location().setIndex(0))));

requests.add(new Request().setInsertText(new InsertTextRequest()
                .setText("Simple test.")
                .setLocation(new Location().setIndex(0))));

BatchUpdateDocumentRequest body = new BatchUpdateDocumentRequest()
                .setRequests(requests);

BatchUpdateDocumentResponse response = docService.documents()
                .batchUpdate(file.getId(), body).execute();
```

This also invokes the same error. How can I properly add text?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Set the index of the `Location` object to 1, since it's 1-indexed.

Comment: Figured this out minutes after posting the question. The fact it's 1-indexed is not mentioned anywhere on the API documentation.

Comment: Thank you! Had the same problem.

Comment: I guess it's just the 3 of us who have ever used the Google API aside from the internal team. Haha. :D

Comment: Whats really annoying is the documentation says that it is 0 based https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#Location

Comment: I guess I am the fourth one.

Comment: One more who uses it

Comment: Google Docs is actually 0-based, but the first item in a document is always the first section break which you can hang section info onto. So when adding content, you are adding it at index 1 inside the first section.

Agreed that this is not clear in the docs.